# Comments not showing in ListView inside Asynctask - android

Tags: android, xml, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` that uses a JSON function to get comments in the `doInBackground` method. It then sends the array of comments to `onPostExecute` where it places the `JSONArray` into a `String[]` then is places the string into `setListAdapter`. The code doesn't crash and everything seems to work right but the comments are not being shown inside the `Activity`.

```
class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        final JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments,
                offsetNumber);
        return json2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
        try {
            if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                final String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1) {

                    final JSONArray array = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
                    final String comments[] = new String[array.length()];
                    for (int i = 1; i <= array.length(); i++) {
                        comments[i] = array.getString(i);
                    }
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DashboardActivity.this,
                            R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, comments));

                }// end if key is == 1
                else {
                    // Error in registration
                    registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                }// end else
            }// end if
        } // end try
        catch (final JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }// end catch
    }
}


new loadComments().execute();
```

My xml for the activity is this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashboardRelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dashboard_post"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/post"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentSection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnPost"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Error message -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/collectComment_error"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/commentSection"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textColor="#e30000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try and debug you app. See at what point does it stop working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged` for your list adapter?

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DashboardActivity.this,
                        R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, comments)
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
```